# Conda/Spyder environment error - js not allowed to load local resource

Tags: python, spyder, conda

**EDIT:** As indicated by @Carlos Cordoba, this problem is a known bug with ipykernel, and will be fixed in the coming weeks. For anyone experiencing the same problem, see [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7842) thread, and use the following command after installing spyder to your environment:

```
conda install -n env_name ipykernel=4.8.2
```

**ORIGINAL:** I'm creating a Python 3.6 environment using Anaconda, and receive the following error in the prompt after installing and running Spyder:

> js: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/User/Anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/site-packages/spyder/utils/help/static/css/default.css

This error continues to print every 15 seconds or so. Steps I've used for creating my environment within Anaconda Prompt:

```
1. conda create -n my_env python

2. conda install -n my_env spyder

3. conda activate my_env

4. spyder
```

What could be causing this, and why am I getting a javascript error when using Python?

Comment: Weirdly, this works fine if I install spyder using conda navigator when the environment is activated.

Comment: js error is syntax highlighting in Spyder

Comment: Also note suggested installation is `conda install -c anaconda spyder` ( with channel )

Comment: Still not working with that modification, I'm going to try reinstalling Conda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error is already fixed and it'll be part of our **3.3.2** version, to be released in a couple of weeks.

Note: About your last question:

> why am I getting a javascript error when using Python?

We have some css and javascript that we use to show info formatted as html (like the documentation rendered in our Help pane).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried : conda install -n env_name ipykernel=4.8.2
But it did not work. Still the same JS problem and the kernel does not start in spyder. A problem only for osx users?

So, you can solve the problem by starting spyder using the anaconda navigator and selecting the version 3.2.8 in the "gear" icon. Then, it is possible to continue to work. Ok, it is not with the latest version but you can work by waiting for the next 3.3.2 version.

"Better" is again the enemy of "very good"